# How change the node count of a created cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I created a cluster with kops in the AWS.

```
sudo kops create cluster --name=k8s.ehh.fun --state=s3://kops-state-ehh000 --zones=us-east-1a --node-count=3 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro --dns-zone=k8s.ehh.fun
```

And now a Would like to change the node-count without destroy the cluster. How can I do that?
I tried :

```
 sudo kops update cluster --name=k8s.ehh.fun --state=s3://kops-state-ehh000 --node-count=3 --node-size=t2.micro
```

But I got : Error: unknown flag: --node-count

Answer (score 10):

You can change the node count by editing the `nodes` instance group:

```
kops edit instancegroup nodes
```

This will open an editor in which you can edit your instance group's specification and increase the code count. After saving and exiting, call:

```
kops update cluster <cluster-name> --yes
```

This will automatically update your auto-scaling group and start additional instances (or terminate them if you decreased the node count).

See [the documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/instance_groups.md#resize-an-instance-group) for more information.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: i am trying to automate this operation using script. Is there a way to do this using command line options without opening Yaml file and edit MaxSize/MinSize option?